# How to select data if prices changes in same day, interval of 7 and 14 day?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to extract data using SQL Code if material being procured on different prices from same/different vendors on same day, in the interval of 7 days or in an interval of 14 days?
I tired but not able to do code for this. I am new in SQL.

Data Table - 
Item  Date  Vendor  Material  Quantity  NetPrice

Comment: please try to explain more exactly what you want to approach and add some testdata - create a http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post the link. 
will make it easier for us to help you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Stackoverflow is for solving problems or debug your codes using coders. Better try your self with sql, Post your codes here and find a solution. Please create schema, tables and other related stuffs, try your self.Butter luck

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: An attempt and input and output data would help us understand what you want.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c738/4 - Data Table .. I am not sure of logic on this. Material prices keep changing by season end even monthly. However it’s a point of concern if material being procured on different prices from same/different vendors on same day, in the interval of 7 days or in an interval of 14 days. These instances must be highlighted in order to enable company X to take necessary action and eliminate the potential losses which can be incurred through procurement at higher prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query retrieves all records for which exists another record within 14 days for the same material with another price. Change 14 to 7 or 0 or any other value you'd like to check.

```
select *
from mytable
where exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where other.material = mytable.material
  and other.netprice <> mytable.netprice
  and abs(datediff(other.date, mytable.date)) <= 14 -- or 7 or 0
)
order by material, date, netprice;
```

Comment: that is not the way to go because that forces him to do queries every time he wants to check. The way to go is a trigger, so that will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TABLE T( Item INT ,Dt DATE ,Vendor INT, PRICE INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T VALUES
    -> (1,'2017-06-12',1,10),(1,'2017-06-25',1,20),
    -> (1,'2017-06-26',1,30),(1,'2017-06-26',1,40),
    -> (2,'2017-06-26',1,10),(2,'2017-06-26',1,40),
    -> (3,'2017-05-26',1,10),(3,'2017-05-26',1,40),
    -> (4,'2017-06-20',1,10),(4,'2017-06-20',1,40),
    -> (5,'2017-06-12',1,10),(5,'2017-06-12',1,40);
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select s.item,
    -> max(case when src = 1 then s.prices else 0 end) as PricesToday,
    -> max(case when src = 2 then s.prices else 0 end) as Prices7,
    -> max(case when src = 3 then s.prices else 0 end) as Prices14
    -> from
    -> (
    -> SELECT 1 as src,item,COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) Prices
    -> FROM T
    -> where dt = date(now())
    -> GROUP BY ITEM HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) > 1
    -> union
    -> SELECT 2,item,COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) Prices
    -> FROM T
    -> where datediff(date(now()),dt) <= 7
    -> GROUP BY ITEM HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) > 1
    -> union
    -> SELECT 3,item,COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) Prices
    -> FROM T
    -> where datediff(date(now()),dt) <= 14
    -> GROUP BY ITEM HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PRICE) > 1
    -> ) s
    -> group by s.item;
+------+-------------+---------+----------+
| item | PricesToday | Prices7 | Prices14 |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+
|    1 |           2 |       3 |        4 |
|    2 |           2 |       2 |        2 |
|    4 |           0 |       2 |        2 |
|    5 |           0 |       0 |        2 |
+------+-------------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: @salmon. Couldn't a trigger also be a workable solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. create a trigger
2. then you want to save the output into another table, so create that new table.
3. Something like this.

   DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER check_price AFTER UPDATE ON your_good_old_table
           FOR EACH ROW
           BEGIN
               IF NEW.price <> OLD.price THEN
                   INSERT INTO your_new_better_table (newprice) 
                   VALUES(NEW.newprice);
               END IF;
           END;
       $$
       DELIMITER;

NOTE: can an editor please format the code? I cant get it with ctrl+ k

Comment: a trigger is not appropriate here not least because you would have to write another query to establish when the changes occurred (and a change today would not be a change today tomorrow)